# PHPExcel - Using example read fiter

Tags: php, filter, spreadsheet, phpexcel

I'm just getting started with PHPExcel. My very large spreadsheets cannot be loaded whole into memory (memory fail). To only load the parts of the worksheet I need, I'm trying to use the MyReadFilter code that was provided in the documentation, but the code is a bit above me and I'm hoping someone can help me understand it.

From the PHPExcel documentation, here's the function:

```
class ReadFilter implements PHPExcel_Reader_IReadFilter 
    { 
    private $_startRow = 0; 
    private $_endRow   = 0; 
    private $_columns  = array(); 

    /**  Get the list of rows and columns to read  */ 
    public function __construct($startRow, $endRow, $columns) { 
        $this->_startRow = $startRow; 
        $this->_endRow   = $endRow; 
        $this->_columns  = $columns; 
        } 

    public function readCell($column, $row, $worksheetName = '') { 
    // Only read the rows and columns that were configured 
    if ($row >= $this->_startRow && $row <= $this->_endRow) { 
        if (in_array($column,$this->_columns)) { 
        return true; 
        } 
    } 
    return false; 
    } 
}
```

I'm using the following lines to invoke PHPExcel

```
//  Get the selected Excel file, passed from form
$testFile = $_FILES['upload_test']['tmp_name'];     
//  Identify the file type of the selected file
$inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($testFile);
//  Create a reader object of the correct file type 
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
//  Instantiate the filter class and apply it to the reader object
$filterSubset = new ReadFilter(1,1000,range('A','Z'));
$objReader->setReadFilter($filterSubset);       
//  Load the selected file into the reader
$objWorkbook = $objReader->load($testFile);
```

I am retrieving data from the resulting worksheet object using this syntax:

```
$someValue= $objWorkbook->getSheet($idx)->getCell('B11')->getCalculatedValue();
```

I'm sure I'll have other questions as I go, but my initial one is about invoking the function. If I change the above line from:

```
$filterSubset = new ReadFilter(1,1000,range('A','Z'));
```

to:

```
$filterSubset = new ReadFilter(1,1000,range('A','AA'));  //Last column changed
```

the entire read fails. I actually only need calculated values from column B, but that column has references as far over as column AS, so I need to read them as well. Can someone please tell me how to use this function to read past column Z, or to modify it? Ideally, what I'd like is to just read the contents of about a dozen columns spread out from B to AS, but I can't figure that out either.

Thanks much for any help.

Comment: I know this isn't exactly the answer you're looking for, but can you take those calculated values in cell B, copy them, "paste-as-value" to a new column, and only use that column for your program? Paste as value will give you the value of the copied cells without the overhead of the calculations.

Comment: Before you get too far into this, are the excel files you're working with WAY too large for memory, or just slightly too large? You could use `ini_set('memory_limit', '128M');` if you need just a little more ram and you know your hardware can handle it. Though using this read filter is going to be your most stable route if you expect even larger files.

Comment: Thx to both. I'm looking for a more robust solution (size is iffy, some files may break it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`range('A','AA');` is not valid try creating your own custom range

Example

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r(xrange('AA', 'ZZ'));
```

Function Used

```
function xrange($start, $end, $limit = 1000) {
    $l = array();
    while ($start !== $end && count($l) < $limit) {
        $l[] = $start;
        $start ++;
    }
    $l[] = $end;
    return $l;
}
```

[See Live Demo](http://eval.in/5742)

Comment: Thanks for this tip, and for the demo. I'll try it tonite.

Comment: Simplify the comparison with: $endTest = $end; $endTest++; while ($start !== $endTest) { to eliminate the more expensive strcmp() function and comparison

Comment: Baba, after monkeying around with your function, it finally occurred to me that I could just create an array with only the columns I needed (plus column A, which is required for some reason). Worked like a charm. Thanks again so much for telling me what the problem was and pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

range('A','AA) isn't a valid range.... PHP's range function doesn't assume that AA follows Z. Try using column numbers instead, using PHPExcel's columnIndexFromString() and stringFromColumnIndex() static methods in the PHPExcel_Cell class to convert 27 to AA and vice versa (watch out for the base value 0 or 1 though).

Comment: Mark, after you and Baba explained to me what the problem was, I was able to come up with a much simpler solution (see reply to above). But I'll still goof around with those tools you recommended just to familiarize myself with them. Thanks again for taking the time to reply.